# Ignore some installed packages in webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, package.json, storybook

My webpack configuration **works fine** with following `package.json`:

```
{
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-three-fiber": "4.0.21"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // more unrelated packages
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    // more unrelated packages
  },
}
```

But when I add `react-three-fiber` to `devDepedencies` ([`storybook` needs it](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#react-peer-dependencies)), it **doesnt work** (the modules are being included in the bundle and there are conflicts with multiple react renderers):

```
{
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-three-fiber": "4.0.21"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // more unrelated packages
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-three-fiber": "4.0.21",
    // more unrelated packages
  },
}
```

Is there any way to ignore these folders from `node_modules`?

This is my webpack configuration:

```js
module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    target: ["web", "es5"],
    output: {
        filename: "index.js",
        pathinfo: false,
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/, 
                loader: "ts-loader",
                options: {
                    transpileOnly: true,
                    experimentalWatchApi: true,
                },
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        "react": {
            commonjs: "react",
            commonjs2: "react"
        },
        "react-dom": {
            commonjs: "react-dom",
            commonjs2: "react-dom"
        },
        "react-three-fiber": {
            commonjs: "react-three-fiber",
            commonjs2: "react-three-fiber"
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: If `storybook` needs it, shouldn't it include them as dependencies and go through auto-resolver?

Comment: @Justinas Using `dependencies` or `devDependencies` is not relevant IMO. Since the folder in `node_modules` exists for both cases while running the build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it using aliases.

I created an alias for `react-three-fiber`:

```json
// package.json

  "devDependencies": {
    "storybook-react-three-fiber": "npm:react-three-fiber@4.0.21",
    // more unrelated packages
  },
```

Execute `npm install`.

I extended the webpack configuration to use it:

```js
// .storybook/main.js

const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.resolve.alias['react-three-fiber'] = path.resolve(__dirname, './../node_modules/storybook-react-three-fiber')
    return config
  },
  // more unrelated config
}
```

Now Storybook is able to use it, and its ignored by the webpack configuration of the project, since the name of the folder at node_modules is `storybook-react-three-fiber` now.